# Docker keeps logging "Network configuration change detected"

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm new to Docker and I'm seeing the following message getting logged every few seconds to `%LocalAppData%\Docker\log.txt`:

```
[15:47:21.036][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[15:47:21.192][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[15:47:27.244][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[15:47:28.279][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
```

This message starts coming right after starting Docker without executing any commands.  The messages seem to be coming out of four threads, in sets of two, each set running about 30 sec from each other.  What is causing this message?  Nothing in my computer's configuration is changing (that I'm aware of).

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise and Docker v18.06.1-ce.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: A little more information: this problem seems to occur whether the "DNS Server" of the "Network" settings is set to "Automatic" or "Fixed"; however, when set to "Automatic" the log has additional info saying `%AppData%\Docker\dhcp.json` and `%AppData%\Docker\resolv.conf` have changed, and they are getting updated but with the same information.

Comment: Is this the right forum for this question? Should I move it to a different community?